# Company recently re-branded months ago and we've not had new contracts

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts

Bit of background: I'm a Developer that worked at company X. For some reason company X decided to have a full "re-brand" and became a brand new company, let's call it company Y. This was about 4-5 months ago. The name on our paychecks have changed to company Y but we've not had any new contracts because as I mentioned Y is a new company (on paper at least, all staff are the same as are the clients).

I've mentioned it to HR and to my manager and head of development and nothing seems to be in place for us to get new contracts.

Other than what I've tried what else is there I could do?

Comment: Why is this an issue if the terms of your contract haven't changed?

Comment: Because our old contracts are to company X are are now void

Comment: Depending on jurisdiction it may be possible that new company Y as successor of company X has to fulfil all obligations of the old company therefor your contract would still be valid. Contact a lawyer.

Comment: You're a developer, not in upper management or a salesperson, so why is this your problem? If this directly affects your paycheck, that's a problem solved by getting another job.

Comment: @Dukeling their name is under the contract; clearly this is their problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

> the name on our paychecks have changed to company Y

*As long as the checks are still clearing* I don't see the problem.  You have informed your manager, now focus on doing your job and leave the rest of it to the executives.

**Short answer**: If your checks stop clearing, then you have something to worry about.

Comment: As this answer sort of hints out, both companies could still exist, Company Y could simply own Company X but all external clients only see Company Y.  Unless you don't get paid you shouldn't worry about it until it comes to renew your employment contract itself.  This would be similar to how Alphabet Inc and Google still both exist.  In my example Alphabet Inc is the company you can own stock in, before Alphabet Inc existed, you owned in Google.  *It is the same company just a different name*

Answer (score 2):

If the company has simply re-branded itself a different name but the legal entity that is the company hasn't changed then there's no need to issue new contracts at all as the old ones are still in effect.